# What's wrong with my php function?

Tags: php

I believe there must be something wrong with my php function's syntax but I'm not sure what it is.  Can anyone spot it?

```
function sortByMetal() {
    global $conn;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM necklaces WHERE metal_id = 1 AND color_id = 2";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);

    $output = "";
    while ($necklaces = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $output .= $necklaces['name'];
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? It's using globals and mysql_* functions!

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: And you shouldn't use `SELECT *` in production code, and you should check if the query succeeded before trying to read the result. And you probably want a delimiter between the names otherwise it will look like "Gold ChainPendantRuby Amulet".

Comment: As for the actual syntax... looks fine to me. The actual problem you're trying to solve (errors, e.g.) would be helpful =)

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. You need to mention was problem are you having, any error or something

Answer (score 7):

While I see no syntax errors, I do see some other not-less-important issues:

1. You're using globals.
2. You're using `mysql_*` functions.
3. You're selecting more data than you need.

Let's address each and one of these:

### You're using Globals

Don't use global variables, instead, pass what you need as an argument to the function:

```
function sortByMetal($conn) {
```

### You're using `mysql_*` Functions

Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

### You're selecting more data than you need

Don't use `SELECT *` if you're only planning to use `name`. You can use `` SELECT `name` `` to only select the data you need.

---

Having learnt all that, I came up with this:

```
/**
 * @param PDO $conn
 *
 * @return string
 */
function sortByMetal(PDO $conn) {
    $query = <<<MySQL
SELECT `name`
  FROM `necklaces`
  WHERE `metal_id` = 1
    AND `color_id` = 2;
MySQL;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = "";
    while ($necklace = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $result .= $necklace['name'];
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Which addresses all of those problems in one go. Please do take the time to read about the links I've provided to learn about what I've done in this code.

Comment: In addition he/she should probably use the MySQL `WHERE` and/or `LIMIT` to minimize the results

Comment: @techexpert: She does use `WHERE`. Look at her query closely :)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I see (besides the other answers very valid points): your output string will be ugly, because you don't separate the words with spaces.

Maybe you could use a different sql query using GROUP_CONCAT, so you will immediately get a nice list of names:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( necklaces.name )
FROM necklaces
WHERE metal_id = 1 AND color_id = 2
GROUP BY NULL; -- force group by
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your tables and $conn are set correctly, I don't see anything that stands out.

Start by adding the line 
`mysql_error();`
after the `$result` line and that should show any mysql errors.

Also, assuming you've already actioned the mysql database connection, you may not need the `,$conn)` in your `mysql_query`.

Try that and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the field is right, or if the global variable is correct.